# Webview load specific URL (Quickly/Glade)

Tags: application-development, pygtk, glade, webkit

I was watching the Ubuntu Developer video about creating your own browser using webkit, but I was wondering if it would be possible to make webkit load a specific website. For instance, if I was to click on the tab "page 3" in my notebook, is there a way to tell webkit to load a specific URL? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have looked around for a solution, but was unable to find any.

Comment: that can be done fairly simply in c using webkit_web_view_load_uri(web_view, const gchar *uri);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to connect to the [switch-page](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkNotebook.html#GtkNotebook-switch-page) signal on your Gtk.Notebook, and in the callback call load_uri() on your Webkit WebView

Comment: And from there, where do I enter the specific URL for webkit to go to?

Comment: @Compt The URL is one of the arguments to the load_uri() method.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry I am a bit new at this.